# wordpress and magento integration

Tags: wordpress, magento, integration

Is it possible to integrate a WordPress website which is already working with a Magento website which is on different server than WordPress.
Can we show the posts/pages and data from any plugins on the Magento's homepage?
Please post your suggestions.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below link for Wordpress and Magneto integration
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration-1.html

Comment: Thanks but I am aware about the fish-pig and all it's setup.
I want to integrate my already working wordpress site with magento.

Comment: means which thing you need to integrate like post, pages or any other ?